# Named Pipes communication failure between a c# and C program

Tags: c#, c, ipc, named-pipes

everyone. My team is currently developing a system that involves two parts: the data organization, UI, etc. in C#, and heavy number crunching in C due to performance requirements. We're trying to squeeze every little bit of performance so, while initially we were communicating both processes using files, we're moving on by communicating both processes through IPC. Specifically named pipes. A simplified version of the C# program that transfers the C program required data is this:

```
String pipeName = "some_random_name";
NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.Out, 2, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.None, 0, 4096);
Process someProcess= new Process();
someProcess.StartInfo.FileName = appDirectory + "someProcess.exe";
someProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
someProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
someProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
someProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

someProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "\\\\.\\pipe\\" + pipeName;
someProcess.Start();
someProcess.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime;

pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
pipeServer.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(lengthOfNextDataSent), 0, 4);
pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();

for (i = 0; i < lengthOfNextDataSent; i++){
    byte[] xBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(SomeOtherIntegerData);
    pipeServer.Write(xBytes , 0, xBytes.Length);
}
```

While the simplified client C code is:

```
fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
read(fd, &received_length, sizeof(int));
for(i = 0; i < received_length; i++){
    read(fd, integer_array[i], 16);
}
close(fd);
```

The weird thing is, I'm able to correctly receive (in the C application) and decode up to 1820~ bytes. If I try to invoke the C# method WaitForPipeDrain or try to flush after after writing 1820~ bytes (in smaller blocks, either integer sized or bigger), a 'Pipe is broken' exception is thrown. If I try to write more bytes than that in one call, the C app crashes when reading.

Edit: A detail I forgot to mention. I'm compiling the C program with a cygwin-like environment (msys2 specifically) using the mingw32-64 compiler.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not how you properly serialize data. Also, how did you allocate the `integer_array[]` in the C-program?

Comment: I'm just sending integers. Which way would be the proper one to do it?  I have tried using the read method in C using a single integer as the receiving buffer, a char array buffer allocated as:  
    char * buf;
    buf = (char *) malloc ( expected_size * sizeof(int) );
or simply as:
   char buf[someSize];

Comment: If you're reading integers, why don't you `read(fd, ..., sizeof(int)`?

Comment: If you want high performance, put the C code in-process (in a DLL, use p/invoke)

Comment: EOF: That was how I first tried to read the integers. For a moment, I thought the result of sizeof was giving me different results in c# and C, so I hardcoded the size. The behavior is the same regardless of the sizeof(int).

Ben: The C code is very complex and not thread-safe. So, we ran into problems when we tried to execute several instances of the code in a DLL. We could modify the C code but it's huge and not a very feasable objective due to time constraints.

Comment: Well, all I can tell you is that the code you've posted doesn't instill confidence. Your comments on trying a `char []` instead are not helping that any. I'd advise posting all relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

You are ignoring the return value of the `read` call and assuming the entire buffer is valid.

On pipes, you must not ignore this.

There was just a discussion about this on Raymond Chen's blog: [Changing the conditions under which ReadFile produces fewer bytes than requested](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151104-00/?p=91961), where it is discussed that under POSIX (which doesn't constrain Win32, strictly speaking, but does set the expectations that the Win32 API is careful to meet) your assumption is valid for ordinary local files, but not for pipes.

Comment: I definetely was ignoring the read bytes results and added a partial read loop to wait for additional data. But still, the writings stops after some amount of transferred bytes. The read function in the C program keeps receiving 0 bytes indefinetely and the c# program either crashes when flushing, or hangs when invoking 'waitForDrain'.

I have to assume this kind of IPC is not possible for mingw32_64 C and C# apps?

Comment: Here is an updated [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151104-00/?p=91961) to Raymond Chen's blog post

Comment: @S.Hooley: Thanks!